# Synonym for a control structure that validates a non-trivial conditional expression

Tags: synonyms, logic

Say I have two doors: one can be entered by *members*, *mailmen*, and *owners*; and the other can be opened by *owners*.

Access through either door is **conditional**, so I can't use that word to describe the the door with more logic.

Is there a synonym for a structure whose condition is the logical *or* of three axioms?

Something like "The triconditional door" (except triconditional is strictly incorrect since its analogue, biconditional, has nothing to do with the logical *or* of two axioms).

Comment: The example of non-trivial is trivial.  ;)

Comment: @TimRomano I don't know what you're getting at.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=trivia+etymology&oq=trivia+etymology&aqs=chrome..69i57.4883j0j8&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=0&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not triconditional. There is only one condition (variable) in both cases, but in the former there are more values (members, mailmen, owners, non-admitees, as opposed to owners, non-admitees). These choices lead to two states, *admit* or *non-admit*. There are really four values in the first example. You might call it a *multi-value* criteria.

Comment: The question correctly states that "triconditional is strictly incorrect" - but your suggestion of multi-value seems quite nice. Will accept unless there's a better idea soon.